# Could not deduce template argument with std::basic_string

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

The striped-down version of my problem:

I want to merge these two functions:

```
void Bar(const std::string &s);
void Bar(const std::wstring &s);
```

..into one templated function:

```
template <class CharType>
void Foo(const std::basic_string<CharType> &s);
```

And I thought I will be be able to call `Foo` like `(1)` and `(2)`, but to my surprise not even `(3)` works.

```
(1) Foo("my string");
(2) Foo(std::string("my string"));
(3) Foo(std::basic_string<char>("my string"));
```

I tried removing the `const` qualifier for parameter `s` and even dropping the  reference (`&`), or calling with `lvalues` instead of `rvalues`, but all with the same result.

The compiler (both gcc and VS - so I am pretty sure it's a standard compliant behaviour) can't deduce the template argument for `Foo`. Of course it works if I call `Foo` like `Foo<char>(...)`.

So I would like to understand why this is, especially since the call `(3)` is a one-to-one type between the type of the calling parameter object and the function argument type.

Secondly, I would like a workaround to this: to be able to use one templated function, and to be able to call it like `(1)` and `(2)`.

**Edit**

`(2)` and `(3)` do work. I was declaring it wrong in my compiler (not like in my question):

```
template <class CharType>
    void Foo(const std::basic_string<char> &s);
```

Sorry about that.

Comment: As far as i can see in VS's implementation `std::string` is not really `basic_string<char>` is `basic_string<char,char_traits<char>,allocator<char> >` so i think it does not work because it is missing some template arguments.

Comment: Edited my answer, might suit your needs now

Comment: Note that you do not need to have the type separate like that. Using `template<class StringT> void Foo(StringT const & s) ...` works the same way and allows for string types other than `std::basic_string<>`. That doesn't help with case (1), unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) won't work because you're trying to use a **const char[10]** instead of a std::string

2) should work and so should 3) since default template parameters should ensure you're using defaults

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class CharType>
void Foo(const std::basic_string<CharType> &s)
{
    cout << s.c_str(); // TODO: Handle cout for wstring!!!
}

void Foo(const char *s)
{
    Foo((std::string)s);
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring mystr(L"hello");
    Foo(mystr);

    Foo("world");

    Foo(std::string("Im"));

    Foo(std::basic_string<char>("so happy"));

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/L63Gkn

Careful when dealing with template parameters. I also provided a small overload for wstring, see if that fits you.

Comment: God, I was declaring it like `template <class CharType>
void Foo(const std::basic_string<char> &s)`. I will edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: That's ok, I don't use my function to write to streams. In my real function I have more string arguments and I generate and return a new string.